# Style only for single post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my single post to have a style different from the main style. I know we can include a custom CSS file in `single.php` but I do not have a `single.php` file in my theme!

I just want a custom id, like `id="single"`, added to the single post (not in main page posts) and then I can write styles for it.

I found some PHP code but I don't know how I can use it, or if it is what I want or not...

```
if (is_single()) {
    $single_css_styling = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'single_css_styling', true);
    if (!empty($single_css_styling)) { ?>
<style type="text/css">
  <?php echo $single_css_styling; ?>
<style>
<?php } }
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you can create custom template and use it's css easily where you want to use.

Comment: You can also add id/class by using jquery

Comment: i'm newbie as you see give more explanation

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21087277/1719246

Comment: Check this plugin for POST TEMPLATE http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/

Comment: To Create Post template follow this thread http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-a-post-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <?php if (is_single()) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("body").addClass("single");});
        </script>';
    } ?>
```

you can now class >> single is added to your body tag
using that identity you can easily apply your css

Note : jQuery file must added to your site for that

**Without jQuery**

```
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
      if (is_single()){
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'single';
    // return the $classes array
      }
    return $classes;
}
```

Please make sure in body tag of header.php

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```

is putted or not

Comment: but i don't want to use jquery on pages, is there any way with php?

Comment: Wordpress single post on add class single at body tag using body_class() so not required for this js put on web.

Comment: @ravipatel It is not by default. You should be using `body_class()` first.

Comment: i add php code in my function.php but don't add any class or id in `article` tag, sorry silly me

Comment: is your body tag in header.php look like **<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>** ???

Comment: yes it's have and your class "single" added but i want to add this class in my `article` tag

Comment: please try to add css **body.single article{ PUT YOUR ALL CSS HERE }** and write it on css your file

Comment: I don't believe that you need the filter. `body_class` will add `single` out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Your theme should use the standard [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) WordPress method in the `<body>` element, as shown in the example in the documentation:

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```

That will automatically add useful classes to the body element, including `single` if it's a single page. Then you just target your CSS at `.single`.